# VW Golf MK4 Airbag Light

Tags: golf, supplemental-restraint-system, mk4

Does anyone know where to find the fault code references
I have a 2002 Golf with the airbag light on. With an Xtool I have the COD 12855 station code 3141
I don't really want to start soldering all the connectors only to still have the light on.
So far I've cleaned the connectors under the seat. And tried a reset….
Knowing the fault code would save a lot of time
Cheers Jez

Comment: Google returns nothing for that code? All I could find>>>>>http://wiki.ross-tech.com/wiki/index.php/Airbag_Coding

Comment: See if you can find someone with a VCDS cable or but one of the cheap ones and use the VCDS Lite software.  I've found Volkswagens implementation of CAB-BUS wanting on some of the early cars but the VCDS software works wonders.  It isn't expensive either.